# Taking input from user and storing (the entire) it into an array with Groovy

Tags: arrays, for-loop, input, groovy

Okay I know I asked a question very similar to this previously, but I need to know how to take several words from the user and store them into an array and print them out. I suspect this will require a for loop. I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
System.in.withReader {
    print  'input: '
    def c1 = it.readLine()
    def c2 = it.readLine()
    def c3 = it.readLine()
    def c4 = it.readLine()
    def c5 = it.readLine()
    def c6 = it.readLine()
    def c7 = it.readLine()
    def c8 = it.readLine()
    def c9 = it.readLine()
    def c10 = it.readLine()
    country = [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10]
    assert country.size() == 10
    for(i=0; i<10;i++)
    {

       println country[i]
    }
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Try this:

```
System.in.withReader {
  def country = []

  for (i in 0..9)
    country << it.readLine()

  country.each() { println it }
}
```

Comment: Is there a function in groovy for reversing the order in which the elements in an array are printed out?

Comment: Sure thing, you can use the Groovy [List#reverse](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#reverse()) method. `country.reverse().each() { println it }`

Comment: I'd say absolutely! It's pretty simple to write, concise, and runs on the JVM. Where I work, we use Groovy (and Grails) quite regularly.

Comment: `System.in.withReader { r -> country = (1..10).collect { r.readLine() } }` would be an alternative way

Comment: The code: country.reverse().each() { println it } failed to print the array in reverse. I get an exit code after I enter the 10 elements

Comment: Ah never mind I used country.reverseEach { println it } and it worked